# Serving zip files as directories in Apache httpd

Tags: zip, apache

Is it possible to configure Apache httpd to treat zip files as if they were directories. I would like to be able to serve a directory tree both as a zip-file and as a directory, but I would like to avoid having to keep both on disk. If possible, I'd like to just have the zip files on disk and let Apache serve them as regular directories, but the otherway around would work too.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not, because zip is sequence structured, means if somebody access the last file in the zip file, the whole zip need to be read to extract the last file.

Comment: I would be ok for me if the entire zip was unpacked automatically. I'm not worried about the space, I want to avoid the administration around unpacking the directory on the server. Just placing a zip file in a certain location is much easier.

Comment: Why not write a script to watch/unzip zip files automatically ?

Comment: Well, I could do that. But if there was built-in support for this, it would be better.

Comment: Zip files are not sequence structured, tar files are. This should be possible.